# I can't moving the turtle

Tags: gis, netlogo

I'm just starting in netlogo to create an agent-based model. I've got 2 shapefiles, and I want to make my turtle move on my network map. For now I have only can managed to load the shapefiles in my model. Could someone give me an idea how to move the turtle on my network map?

Here is my code so far:

```
extensions [gis]
breed [cars car]
turtles-own [destination]
globals [
  states-dataset 
  car-blue]

to custom-clear
  reset-ticks
  clear-turtles
  clear-patches
  clear-drawing
  clear-all-plots
end

to setup
  clear-all
  custom-clear
  ask patches [set pcolor green - 3]
  set states-dataset gis:load-dataset "C:/Users/ADMIN/Documents/QGIS/Export Netlogo/Format .shp/state.shp"

  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of states-dataset
  gis:set-drawing-color yellow
  gis:draw states-dataset 1

  set route-car-blue gis:load-dataset     "C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/routefiles/Shapefile/car/route-car-blue.shp"
  gis:set-drawing-color blue
  gis:draw angkot-permatabiru 1.5

  foreach gis:feature-list-of route-car-blue
  [car-pb -> let location gis:location-of gis:centroid-of car-pb
   create-turtles 5 [
    set xcor item 0 location
    set ycor item 1 location
    set shape "car"
    set size 1
  ]]
end

to go
  ask turtles [
  let new-location one-of [link-neighbors] of destination
  move-to new-location
  set destination new-location]
  tick
end
```

Does anybody know to fix my code? I want to make my turtle move based on my network map.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in the circularity of your `destination` and `new-location`. You define `new-location` as being a `link-neighbor` of your `destination`, but since you don't have a `destination` yet, this `new-location` is set to `nobody`. You then set your `destination` to be your `new-location`, which also sets `destination` to nobody, ending up in a circle where no movement is happening.

The fix for this would be to define a `destination` for each turtle during `setup`